# Geom_text function does not dodge some values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am having issues on dodging some values on a plot with R.
My goal is to create a point plot to see how three variables (Environmental sustainability, economic sustainability, and social sustainability) change according to the type of company.
I am facing some difficulties in dodging the values of one variable, that is "Economic sustainability". As you can see in the image, the function *position = position_dodge* succeeded in dodging the "environmental sustainability" (green), and "social sustainability" (blue) variables. But for "economic sustainability" (yellow) variable, the values are overlapping the yellow shape.

Someone can help me to fix it?

The code I created is the following:

```
ggplot(DS, aes(x=Valore, y=Azienda, fill=Sostenibilità_effettiva, colour=Sostenibilità_effettiva))
+ geom_point(aes(shape=Sostenibilità_effettiva, color=Sostenibilità_effettiva),stat = "identity", size=1.5) 
+ theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 5, family="Helvetica"), axis.title=element_text(size=7, family="Helvetica", face="bold"), axis.text.x=element_text(size=6, family="Helvetica"), axis.text.y=element_text(size=6, family="Helvetica"), legend.title=element_text(size=7, family="Helvetica"), legend.text=element_text(size=6, family="Helvetica"), panel.background=element_blank(), legend.position = "top", axis.line=element_line(color="black"), axis.ticks=element_line(color="black"), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.25, linetype = 3)) 
+ geom_vline(data=media_importanza, aes(xintercept=Mean, color=Sostenibilità_effettiva), linetype = "dashed", size=0.5) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#4cb71e", "#fabd01", "#197bd3"))
+ geom_text(data = DS, aes(label=Valore),color="black", position=position_dodge(width = 1), hjust=.5, size=2)
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

There is a dodge - see example below. You have three categories, one is dodged upward, the other downwards, and the last remains in the middle.

Where would you like to dodge it to? There are only two dimensions on your paper.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(mean(Sepal.Length), y = "x")) +
  geom_text(aes(color = Species, label = Species), position = position_dodge(width = .5))
```

[image]

#### you could use nudge

```r
library(dplyr)

iris_foo <- iris %>%
  ## just an example
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(sepal = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ## make a nudge column
  mutate(nudge = c(-1, 1, 2))

ggplot(iris_foo, aes(sepal, y = "x")) +
  geom_text(aes(color = Species, label = Species), nudge_y = iris_foo$nudge)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>